# Component can not access ViewChild after injection in page

Tags: angular, ionic3

In a brand new project with ionic 3 and Angular4, I am having a @Component that renders something in a canvas like so:

**analyzer-chart.html:**

```
<div>
  <canvas #chartCanvas></canvas>
</div>
```

**analyzer-chart.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'analyzer-chart',
  templateUrl: 'analyzer-chart.html'
})
export class AnalyzerChartComponent {

  @ViewChild('chartCanvas') chartCanvas;
```

and later

```
new Chart(this.chartCanvas.nativeElement
```

This component is used in an @IonicPage (AnalyzerPage) and works very well.

But now I want to call a method from AnalyzerChartComponent in analyzer.ts and therefore want to inject that component in the constructor of the page like so:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-analyzer',
  templateUrl: 'analyzer.html',
  providers: [AnalyzerChartComponent]
})
export class AnalyzerPage {

  pageTitle:string = "loading...";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
     public analyzerChart: AnalyzerChartComponent
    ) {
  }
```

And then, by injecting the component into the page, it stops working because the @ViewChild('chartCanvas') chartCanvas is suddenly undefined. Don't know why.

The analyzer.html is simply like

```
<ion-content padding>

  <h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
  <analyzer-selection-form></analyzer-selection-form>
  <br />
  <analyzer-chart></analyzer-chart>

</ion-content>
```

What is the correct way to call members in the included component?

Comment: but is `analyzerChart` not `undefined` in the constructor? are you trying to inject child component?

Comment: No, it's not undef in the constructor - and yes, I am trying to inject a child component.

Comment: well, then [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44891497/2545680) should help

Answer (score 1):

Angular updates `@ViewChild('chartCanvas') chartCanvas;` when it runs change detection. Until it does that the `chartCanvas` will be undefined. And Angular runs change detection after it creates all views. It calls constructors when it creates views. So you're here trying to inject a component

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
     public analyzerChart: AnalyzerChartComponent
    ) {
```

before Angular ran change detection for it. Wait for change detection. Use `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.analyzerChart.chartCanvas
}
```

Read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) for more details.

Comment: I have tried to call into the analyzerChart Component from the ngAfterViewInit() of the page component analyzer.ts - unfortunately chartCanvas is still undefined. When the parent (page) ngAfterViewInit() is called, will the child component ngAfterViewInit() be called, too?

Comment: yes, it has been called for all children, read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Comment: _unfortunately chartCanvas is still undefined_ - can you create a plunker? [it's not possible to inject a child component](https://plnkr.co/edit/FGZw4L1oVqgabmW9j8DJ?p=info), so maybe you didn't show the case clearly

Answer (score 0):

I was totally wrong. Instead of trying to inject the subcomponent (like I used to do it in like JSF etc.) I should use standard angular data binding like so:

```
 <analyzer-chart [analyzerResponse]="analyzerResponse"></analyzer-chart>
```

And then set the data in the parent component like so:

```
private analyzerResponse:BacktestResult = xxx;
```

And responde to change events in the subcomponent like so:

```
 @Input() 
  analyzerResponse:BacktestResult;

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('Hello AnalyzerChartComponent::ngOnChangeData');
    if (this.analyzerResponse && this.chartCanvas) {
      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.destroy();
      }
      this.setupChart(600);
    }
  }
```

Next time I finish my manual-readings before asking. Thanks anyway to Maximus!